# WiX - Switch InstallScope from perUser to perMachine

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to create an installer that supports perUser and perMachine installations dependent on a selection of setup types on the UI.

- The perUser setup type installs the application into "WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS" and shall require no admin permissions.
- The perMachine setup type install the application into "ProgramFilesFolder" and shall request an UAC dialog.

My attempt was to initially set the Package/@InstallScope to perUser and then modify the ALLUSERS property later on.

If the user selects the perMachine setup type I'm trying to set the ALLUSERS property to 1 doing the following:

```
<Publish Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1">1</Publish>
```

The "Install" buttons gets an UAC icon, but no UAC dialog appears after I pressed it!

[image]

Instead I get an error message that I obviously have no privileges to install the application for all users of the machine.

Is it a bug that no UAC dialog appears or intended? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone from the [WiX Mailing list](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/mailinglist/) pointed me to the [Single Package Authoring article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx) on msdn.

I had to initialize the following properties:

```
<Property Id='ALLUSERS' Value='2' />
<Property Id='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='1' />
```

and set the 'MSIINSTALLPERUSER' property to an empty string for a per-Machine installation.

```
<Publish Property="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="{}">1</Publish>
```

Be aware that this only works for Windows Installer 5 and higher!